# Creating an online Asset Library/Catalogue? Help

Tags: database, wordpress, drupal, joomla

I've been asked to look in to creating and online database for sorting flash banners. So its kind of like a big resource library where our client can log on search and browser for old/existing banner creatives.

Does anyone have any recommendations on what I should do/look in to. CMS Framesworks etc.

I'm pretty sure I could use Wordpress for this job via custom post types etc. But I think there's probably a better solution out there. Drupal? Joomla? Expression Engine? Or would it be better to just create a basic cms from scratch.

Features needed:

- Kick arse search functionality (am guessing the client will likely try to search for creative by year, month, campaign, banner type.
- Smart navigation
- Sharing is convenient
- Must be able to demo working demos of expanding banners as well as non-expanding
- CMS so new ads can be easily added to the library.

Thanks in advance for you knowledgeable insights :P

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Although basic Joomla has own extension for this purpose, here:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/banner-management , you have got a whole set of advanced extensions which do the job for you in Joomla. Read opinions and choose your favourite